# Is it Possible to Dynamically Generate Dropdown Items?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu

I'm working in react, and for one part of the project I need x amount of dropdown menus. Each dropdown menu will have y amount of options to choose from.
Usually with things like this, I can just use a simple map function and I am good to go, however the syntax gets a little tricky since one `DropdownMenu` has many `Dropdown.Items`. My code looks like this, no errors pop up and the console.log statements return exactly what is to be expected, but absolutely nothing renders.

```
const renderDefaultScheduling = () => {
        return allDevices.map( (device, superIndex) => {
            <Card>
                {renderAllOfThisDevice(device, superIndex)}
            </Card>
        })
    }

    const renderAllOfThisDevice = (deviceObj, superIndex) => {
        let oneDeviceDropdowns = []
        console.log(deviceObj)
        for (let i = 1; i <= deviceObj.amount; i = i + 1){
            let thisOptions = renderDropDownOptionsFromList(deviceObj, superIndex)
            oneDeviceDropdowns.push(
                <DropdownButton title={deviceObj[i]}>
                    {thisOptions}
                </DropdownButton>
            )
        }
        return(
            <Card>
                <Card.Title>{deviceObj.name}</Card.Title>
                <Card.Body>
                    {oneDeviceDropdowns}
                </Card.Body>
            </Card>
        )
    }

    const renderDropDownOptionsFromList = (deviceObj, superIndex) => {
        console.log(deviceObj)
        return deviceObj.remaining_drivers.map( (driver, index) => {
            <Dropdown.Item key={index} onClick={() => handleDriverSelection(deviceObj, driver, index, superIndex)}>
                {driver.firstname} {driver.lastname}
            </Dropdown.Item>
        })
    }
```

What gets me, is not even the `<Card.Title>{deviceObj.name}</Card.Title>` line renders, which is not inside the nested map, only the first layer of it... So if `deviceObj` is logging properly, I see legitimately no reason why that line wouldn't be rendering. Does anyone have any ideas, am I evenm able to do this with DropDown Menus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no data is showing beacuse you are not returning it from the map function callback in  `renderDefaultScheduling` and `renderDropDownOptionsFromList`

i have marked the return statement with ****return****

```
const renderDefaultScheduling = () => {
            return allDevices.map( (device, superIndex) => {
              ****return****  <Card>
                    {renderAllOfThisDevice(device, superIndex)}
                </Card>
            })
        }
const renderAllOfThisDevice = (deviceObj, superIndex) => {
    let oneDeviceDropdowns = []
    console.log(deviceObj)
    for (let i = 1; i <= deviceObj.amount; i = i + 1){
        let thisOptions = renderDropDownOptionsFromList(deviceObj, superIndex)
        oneDeviceDropdowns.push(
            <DropdownButton title={deviceObj[i]}>
                {thisOptions}
            </DropdownButton>
        )
    }
    return(
        <Card>
            <Card.Title>{deviceObj.name}</Card.Title>
            <Card.Body>
                {oneDeviceDropdowns}
            </Card.Body>
        </Card>
    )
}

const renderDropDownOptionsFromList = (deviceObj, superIndex) => {
    console.log(deviceObj)
    return deviceObj.remaining_drivers.map( (driver, index) => {
       ****return**** <Dropdown.Item key={index} onClick={() => handleDriverSelection(deviceObj, driver, index, superIndex)}>
            {driver.firstname} {driver.lastname}
        </Dropdown.Item>
    })
}
```